# Flutter: Shared Preference or Scoped Model for speed

Tags: database, performance, dart, flutter, persistent-storage

I will be storing many small data strings in both scoped model and shared preferences. My question is, in order to retrieve this data back are there any significant speed differences in retrieving this data from either of these sources?
Since I will be doing many "sets" and "gets" I would like to know if anybody has seen any differences in performance using one more than another.

I understand Shared preferences is persistent and scoped model is not however after the app is loaded, the data is synced and I would rather access the data from the fastest source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, understand that they are not alternatives. You will likely want to back certain parts of your model using shared preferences and this can be done behind scoped model (or BLoC etc). Note that simply updating a shared preference will **not** trigger a rebuild, which is why you should use one of the shared state patterns and then have that update those items it wants to persist to shared preferences.

Shared preferences is actually implemented as an in memory map that triggers a background write to storage on each update. So 'reads' from shared preferences are inexpensive.

Comment: Thank you for the details. I appreciate it.